# parse ArrayList to Date

Tags: java, date, arraylist

I have an array list with string and I would like to convert it in Date. Seems 'parse' cannot be used to do this, within the following piece of code:

```
List<String> eventsList = Arrays.asList("2015-06-02 00:15", "2015-06-02 22:15", "2015-06-03 00:18");
List<Date> eventsDate = new SimpleDateFormat("y-M-d H:m").parse(eventsList);
```

But that doesn't work.

Could you help me please?

Comment: Do you know what a loop is?

Comment: You can only parse individual Strings - you will need to do that in a loop.

Comment: yes I know what a loop is, but I thought loop can be avoided here - sorry, I didn't precise this

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-java.text.ParsePosition-) for `parse` clearly indicates the type of parameters it accepts.

Comment: yes, that's why I thought it exists an alternative to `parse`, which can be used without a loop. Sorry if this question looks silly, I am a newbie with Java... :/

Answer (score 0):

There's no `parse` method with `List<String>` as a parameter which is why your code won't compile.

There's a [`parse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)) that accepts a `String`. You can use that with a loop or a stream to get the result you need.

Further reading on the available methods of `SimpleDateFormat` can be done [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: ok guys, thank you very much, I understand that loop is the only solution! It's working like that! Thanks a lot for you help. Now I need to work a bit more to have a better understanding of how Java is working.